# How to know terminal's exact name in Linux?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel

I've met problems when I edit MakeFile, and the original code is as below:

```
 TERMINAL :=terminator
 debug: 
 $(UCOREIMG)
 $(V)$(QEMU) -S -s -parallel stdio -hda $< -serial null &
 $(V)sleep 2
 $(V)$(TERMINAL)  -e "cgdb -q -x ./tools/gdbinit"
```

And when I use the command"make debug", I was given:

```
/bin/sh: 1: terminator: not found
Makefile:221: recipe for target 'debug' failed
make: *** [debug] Error 127
```

Comment: Did you try to replace `terminator` with a terminal emulator that you have on your system, such as `xterm` or `gnome-terminal`?

Comment: Indenting everything with a single space is probably part of the problem. `TERMINAL` and `debug` should be blocked-left. The stuff under `debug:` should be indented with a tab. Also see [Can you make valid Makefiles without tab characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2131213/608639), [When to use space or tab in Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28712585/608639), [What is the reasoning behind the Makefile whitespace syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1755550/608639), etc.

Comment: That's exactly what I am confusing, I've tried several emulator's name, they just didn't work. I want to know what the emulator's name is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do several things:

- Install `terminator` on your system.  This can be the best option, as your `Makefile` requests for it.
- Use another terminal emulator like `xterm` or `gnome-terminal` for that.  `cgdb` will run on them without any problem also, and you'll have a fast way to solve the problem without having to dig where `terminator` comes from.  For this, just substitute `terminator` with `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` in the Makefile.
- If you run on a linux console, without the possibility of launching a virtual terminal application, then you have to do more work and switch to another console an execute there the command by hand.  For that:

  ```
  # switch to tty02, for example.
  cd "the/directory/where/the/terminator/program/was/tried"
  cgdb -q -x ./tools/gdbinit
  ```